# Diagnosing appengine java backend hangs in deployed apps

Tags: java, google-app-engine

We are using backends to parallelize large batches of work for our 
users. This involves adding 100's of tasks to a dedicated queue which 
spreads the tasks across 5 dynamic backends. Many of these tasks do a 
url fetch to external web services.

When we run this for one user it seems to work fine but as soon as we 
run it for many users (e.g. in a nightly batch run) we see most of the 
backends eventually stopping processing new tasks.

We've tried rate limiting it but that has not helped either. I can manually stop the 
backends that are frozen and new ones will fire up and start 
processing until they too freeze. Eventually it all completes after a 
few iterations of stopping frozen servers.

Obviously this is severely limiting our ability to scale so I'm 
wondering how to diagnose this problem. We cannot reproduce this on 
localhost since its not really multi-threaded and doesn't truly 
replicate the deployed data patterns.

We could possibly handle this by using pull queues but that's more 
code to write and I'd rather let the queue/backend scheduler do that 
work for us.

What I'd like to do is attach a profiler or jconsole to a backend - that would 
immediately tell me where the freezes are coming from. Is that even 
possible? If not, does anybody have any other tricks that we could use 
to diagnose frozen backends?

fyi : the "frozen" instances have varied levels of memory from 150mb 
to 250mb i.e. it could be a memory leak but the memory numbers don't really support that, they consume zero cpu when frozen and process no new tasks.

Thanks for your attention and help, Steve

Answer (score 2):

In the past I've used Java [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/). You can attach it to a remotely running JVM and use it to take memory dumps and check out CPU/Thread usage, etc. It's really handy for figuring out stuff like this.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up but I don't think this can be attached to a GAE backend right?

Comment: I've never used GAE, but I would assume that they either allow access to the server instance or have some remote debugging capability.